# Azure API Management does not validate required properties in payload

Tags: azure, openapi, azure-api-management

We are using Azure API Management in a project, and we want APIM to be our shield against invalid requests. Since we've already specified what a valid request looks like in our OpenAPI specification and uploaded that to APIM, it seems like a reasonable assumption.

I have specified a component in our OpenAPI (version 3.0.1) specification like this:

```yaml
TemperatureRange:
  description: Defines a desired temperature range
  required:
    - min
    - max
  properties:
    min:
      type: number
    max:
      type: number
```

When uploaded to APIM the schema looks fine:

```json
{
    "required": [
        "min",
        "max"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "min": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "max": {
            "type": "number"
        }
    },
    "description": "Defines a desired temperature range"
}
```

However, when I call an API that uses this definition, I can leave out properties even though they are marked as required.

The payload I sent looks like this, leaving out the required `max` property:

```json
[{
    "someProperty": "someValue",
    "temperatureRange": {
        "min": -18,
    }
}]
```

I can't find any documentation on this and it isn't mentioned in any [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions). What is the intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is functionality that has been requested but has not been implemented: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/17369008-schema-validation-in-apim

Comment: Thanks for finding this, looks like I'm not alone in wanting it at least.